# Application not able to access the profile pic and posts using DjangoAllAuth

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I am trying to access the profile picture and posts of the user using `Django-AllAuth`. Here is the template where I am trying to load the profile image:

```
<html>


<body>

 Welcome back {{ user.first_name }} {{ user.age }}
 <img src={{user.cover.source}} height="60" width="60">

<a href="/">Home</a>
</body>


</html>
```

Here is the `view.py`

```
def fb_personality_traits(request):
    # logger.debug('FB Page Loaded')
    return render(request, 'home/facebook_personality_traits.html')
```

**Settings.py**

```
SITE_ID = 1

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/facebook_personality_traits/'
SOCIALACCOUNT_QUERY_EMAIL = True
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'facebook': {
        'SCOPE': ['email', 'user_posts', 'public_profile', 'user_photos'],
        # 'AUTH_PARAMS': {'auth_type': 'reauthenticate'},
        'METHOD': 'js_sdk',
        'FIELDS': [
            'id',
            'email',
            'name',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'cover',
            'posts',
            'age',
        ],
        'EXCHANGE_TOKEN': True,
        'VERIFIED_EMAIL': True,
        'VERSION': 'v2.10',
    }
}
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_ON_GET = True
```

Here I am not getting the image. See the below result:

[image: current image]

What I want to achieve?

1) I want to display the profile image on the screen.

2) I want to get the posts of the user loggedin in the `view.py` and send it on the screen to display on the template.

Comment: any UI console logs?

Comment: There isn't anything on the log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Non-essential fields like `age` and `cover` aren't persisted by django-allauth. Only common fields are persisted in the `User` model automatically ([see fields](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/3c354af3b5b99d3da66b442fd65a045b7dc15f51/allauth/socialaccount/providers/facebook/provider.py#L182-L187)). You would need to handle this yourself, by capturing the data and storing it somewhere, like your database. These fields are only retrieved and accessible on the post-login response ([see example method](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/3c354af3b5b99d3da66b442fd65a045b7dc15f51/allauth/socialaccount/providers/facebook/provider.py#L33-L35)), where they can be found in the `extra_data` dictionary.

I'd recommend calling [`get_avatar_url`](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/3c354af3b5b99d3da66b442fd65a045b7dc15f51/allauth/socialaccount/providers/facebook/provider.py#L37-L41) on the `SocialAccount` instance (in this case, Facebook) after successful log-in and storing this value in your database. In the case of Facebook, the user avatar URL shouldn't change over time.